# How to only affect one coordinate of a sprite in sprite-kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've been mucking around with sprite-kit but found out the only way to affect a sprites coordinate is with `sprite.position`, the issue here is I only want to affect one sprite coordinate, let's say `y`. How would I do this?

Comment: sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y+10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read up on [SKActions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

```
SKAction *moveSprite = [SKAction moveToY:200 duration:0]; // or wherever...
[yourSpriteInstance runAction:moveSprite];
```

There is also a `moveToX:duration:`, `moveTo:duration:`, `moveBy:duration:` to mention a *few* of the options..

---

Like @sangony writes in the comments you can of course access the node's position directly through its position property:

`sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y + 200);`

This *will* work just fine.

That being said, `SKActions` is the way to go about this in most real-life scenarios: E.g. if you want to have the sprite change its position after 3 seconds, then wait another 2 seconds before it begins rotating. It really is one of the cornerstones of the SpriteKit framework...

Comment: Is there no other way as I wish not to use a duration, instantly would be preferable.